# Nexus 5 "Ok Google" voice output in a non-English US language

Tags: languages, nexus-5, google-now, voice-command, ok-google

I'm trying the have vocal output from my nexus 5 with a non english system language.

If my system language is English(US) I say "ok google" and it opens google now, I say "what's the weather like today" and it show me a weather-widget with the weather and the phone speaks.

Otherwise, if my system language is Italian, and I set English(US) in the voice settings, if I say "ok google" it opens google now, but if I say "what's the weather like today" nexus simply search it in web: no widget, no voice!

**My question is:** it is possible to have the (english) output voice feedback from my questions in google now without setup English(US) with system language?

Many Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I doubt that unless your phone would use a proxy located in US. So yes it is posible...

Comment: You doubt that...so yes? So what, yes or no? :) And could you please explain what that has to do with a proxy? To my knowledge, that's just bound to the system language, not to the location.